# A problem I have with getting a box on my home page for visitors to sign up for a mailing list?

Tags: contacts

I am running CiviCRM under WordPress on a local host

I have set up a Group named "Mailing List" with "Join Our Mailing List" as the description.

Under Group Type "Mailing List" is checked - and I've tested with "Access Control" both checked and unchecked.  Visibility is set to "Public Pages".  Reserved Group? is unchecked.  Is Active? is checked.

I can enter contacts in the back end on Word Press and they appear as contact in CiviCRM, but there is no box on the front end --something that will appear to a user who is not logged in -- in which a user can enter himself as a contact.  What must I do to get a box in "Public Pages" where a visitor can enter his name and email address and have this information become part of the CiviCRM mailing list group?

Comment: There are instructions here about using a link but am unclear if it works for WP. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/set-up/#using-the-subscribe-link

Answer (score 1):

As peterdnz says, the documentation is at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/set-up/ (Using a Profile). 
For WordPress I think the easiest way to display a form publicly is by using a shortcode. After preparing a WordPress Page, click the CiviCRM button above the editor. For Page Type select Profile. On the next drop-down that appears, select the name of the profile that you have created. Select Edit on the radio button option just below the drop-downs, so that you give users access to edit data in your database (i.e. to add their email address and name to your database). Click Insert Form and the shortcode will be added to the editor.
Hope this helps

Comment: Be aware that the CiviCRM button isn't there in the new Block Editor so you have to use the Classic Editor.

Comment: Thanks, Peterb!  The link you sent me solved my problem.